# jqGrid dynamic select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have been following this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/07/02/jqgrid-dynamically-loading-select-options.aspx) from 2009 for a how to do it.

the json object (which is a valid object) returned is...

```
{"Refs":{"str":"1:Airport;3:Customer Location;4:Hotel;2:Regional Office;"}}
```

In my js I'd doing...

```
var getRefIdUrl="http://blah?_service=appdev94&_program=tastest.jsonRefPoints.sas&action=getRefId";

var refs = $.ajax({url: getRefIdUrl, async: false, success: function(data, result) {if (!result) alert('Failure to retrieve the Reference Types.');}}).responseText;
```

In the colmodel I'm doing...

```
  {name:'typeID', index: 'typeID', width: 80, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: 'select',  formatter:'select' ,editrules: { required: true } , editoptions:{value:refs}},
```

This does return the value into the var refs. In the grid view mode it looks great and matches the underlying value to the correct text display. Brilliant.

When I click on EditGridRow the dropdown looks accurate, but when I inspect the element it appears like this...

```
<option role="option" value="{Content""> {"str": 1:Airport</option>
<option role="option" value="3">Customer Location</option>
<option role="option" value="4">Hotel</option>
<option role="option" value="2">Regional Office</option>
<option role="option" value=""}}">undefined</option>
```

Notice how the first and last are funky...
This would lead me to believe the returning json object is NOT in the correct format.

But before I spend too much time exploring this I want to find out how you'd do it in 2014. That link dates back to 2009. Every existing row will have a valid value in my data but if I want to add a new record then I think I'd prefer it to have it say "select a value" or something in the dropdown list as opposed to undefined.

I appreciate any help. Thanks...

Comment: have you tried using editoptions:{value:refs[str]}

Comment: When I change it to...
    {value:refs[str]}
I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: str is not defined"

Comment: sorry, use this  {value:refs.str}

Comment: Well, technically no console error but nothing is displayed in the grid or in the editGridRow. The json object specifically looks like this...
    {
    "Content": {
    "str": "1:Airport;3:Customer Location;4:Hotel;2:SAS Regional Office;"
  }
}

Comment: it should work actually. see this http://jsfiddle.net/LaLET/3/ it is working. Can you try using single quotes with str {value:refs['str']}

Comment: No errors but no values either. I get what you are saying...
 editoptions:{value:refs['str']}

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON object is:

```
{"Content":{"str":"1:Airport;3:Customer Location;4:Hotel;2:Regional Office;"}}
```

then use:

```
 editoptions:{value:refs.Content.str}}
```

Comment: There are actually two ways to load information in a dropdown, but based on your JSON this is the only one applicable.